# Before-filter for all POST requests in Sinatra?

Tags: ruby, filter, sinatra

Is there a way to create a "before" filter to capture and pre-process all POST requests in Sinatra?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

One way of doing this would be to create a custom [condition](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Conditions) to use in the filter:

```
set(:method) do |method|
  method = method.to_s.upcase
  condition { request.request_method == method }
end

before :method => :post do
  puts "pre-process POST"
end
```

Comment: You need Sinatra 1.2.0 or higher for this to work. I just learned it a hard way ;)

Answer (score 14):

Your solution is fully valid.

I would do it like this:

```
before do
  next unless request.post?
  puts "post it is!"
end
```

Or, you can also use a catch-all post route that then hands on the request (needs to be first post route):

```
post '*' do
  puts "post it is!"
  pass
end
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't even consider the `post` method. I like the second approach better -- it's more clear what the code is about, and doesn't pollute the higher-level `before do` namespace.

Comment: With that second option, I believe you have to make sure that post handler is called *before* all the other post handlers (that do the "real" post handling work).

Answer (score 11):

+1 on [matt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/214790/matt)'s answer above... I ended up expanding it to include support for one or many methods like so:

```
set :method do |*methods|
    methods = methods.map { |m| m.to_s.upcase }
    condition { methods.include?(request.request_method) }
end

before method: [:post, :patch] do
    # something
end
```

Answer (score 4):

I came up with this:

```ruby
before do
    if request.request_method == "POST"
        puts "pre-process POST"
    end
end
```

... but if anyone knows a better way, please share.

Comment: Yes that's the way to go, as [documented](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Filters)

Comment: I know about filters. I was wondering if testing the `request.request_method` is best way to go about creating a global pre-POST filter.